# Data is lost after deleting the vault-0 pod for hashivault

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, persistent-volumes, vault, hashicorp

We are deploying vault as helm based deployment. We have configure/enabled the server datastorage mountpath also.
After deployment a new pvc is also getting created and getting bound to local-storage PV.

```
data-vault-0   Bound    local-pv-f69fbb0   10Gi       RWO            local-storage   69s
local-pv-f69fbb0          10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound         vault/data-vault-0                                local-storage            2m55s
```

But when we are deleting the pod vault-0 and once it comes back, then we are loosing all the data(secrets, configurations,policies) we created in vault.

Even though pv,pvc remains intact after deleting the pod.

vault-0 server config

```
 Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
       Recovery Mode: false
             Storage: file
             Version: Vault v1.11.3, built 2022-08-26T10:27:10Z
```

Comment: Since you are using the `file` storage backend, and the PV mount is at `vault/data-vault-0`, what is the filesystem path in the server configuration file? Does it match? Consider also using Raft so this just mostly works automatically.

Comment: @MattSchuchard PV is mount at /data/local-pv1 path in my VM and we have specified the same path as mountpath for our server data storage ..but still we are loosing all data and vault goes back to uninitialized stage.